# how to convert an .exe file to xap file

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2008

I have build an app in Visual Studio 2008 for windows mobile but the output in the release and debug folder are given in `.exe` file. I can't find any `.xap` file to install on a mobile device? What should I do now?

Comment: Maybe it will convert if you download a newer version of Visual Studio? The newest is [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile used the .NET Compact Framework. Windows Phone uses Silverlight or WinRT (better choose WinRT as Silverlight will eventually be left out). Long story short: the frameworks are **way** too different to allow any direct conversion. You may be able to keep the logic part but the UI will have to be rewritten from scratch. Not to mention that the OS is completely different and applications are now sandboxed: there's a lot of things that you could do in Windows Mobile but are impossible on Windows Phone.

Even for the Visual Studio project there's no conversion path. You'll have to create a brand new project and keep whatever you can.